# Prime numbers upto 10^8 using sieve

Tags: java, arrays, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Why this code is working only number less than 10^4? i need to find all the  prime numbers less than 10^8 but this is showing arrayindexoutofbound exception? why? i know we can only create array till size10^8(correct me if i am wrong)  but this is not even working for 10^5.

```
 class Prime
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            boolean[] prime = new boolean[100000000];
            prime[2]=true;
            int i;
            for(i=3; i<100000000; i+=2)
                prime[i]=true;
            for(i=3; i<100000000; i++)  
            {
                if(prime[i]==true)
                    for(int j=i*i; j<100000000; j=j+i)
                        prime[j]=false;
            }
            for(i=1; i<100000000; i++)
            {
                if(prime[i]==true)
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You never use half your array.  You never access `prime[4]` for example.  You might also want to look at a `bitset` instead of a boolean array.

Comment: @rossum i am using prime sieve and i already assumed that even numbers except 2 are not prime number.

Comment: @Eran thanks. but thats not the point...this is just an example....i want to run this code for 10^8 numbers.

Comment: @Eran i want to run this for 10^8 number, but any number greater than 10^4 is showing arrayindexoutofbound exception.

Comment: @Eran can you pls now look at the code and tell why this is showing arrayindexoutofbound exception? i edited the post

Comment: @Eran then how can i correct it? i want this exact logic in my code.

Comment: @Eran  incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int......
                                prime[j]=false;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(int j=i*i; j<100000000; j=j+i)
```

Since `i` can be as large as 99999999, `i*i` may be higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which will cause numeric overflow. As a result, `j` will be initialized to a negative value, and `prime[j]` will throw an exception.

To fix the problem, you can simply add a condition that requires the `j` must be positive:

```
for(int j=i*i; j > 0 && j<100000000; j=j+i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j=i*i; j<10000; j=j+i)
```

if i is 10^5, then the j would be 10^10, which would cause overflow for int type (max value of int type is 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647)

Comment: how to correct it then? i want to find all the prime numbers less then 10^8. this is just an example

Comment: i didnt focus on your logic yet, just re-try to change int type to long type to see if it works

Comment: it is not working as array only take integer as it size.